# portrait AND Landscape VS. portrait and landscape separate

Tags: html, css

Should I use landscape and portrait together like

`@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {}`

OR separate like

`@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {}` for landscape

`@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {}` for portrait

Or all together? Whats the difference here?

Answer (score 0):

The top query will only target screen widths **between** `320px` and `480px`.

`@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {}` will target anything wider than `321px`.

`@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {}` will target anything smaller than `320px`.

You could add something like `@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (orientation: landscape) {}` which will only return true if the device is `320px` or wider **and** in landscape.

`(orientation: portrait)` is also allowed in media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do them together if you put the orientation with the media query

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation: landscape),
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait)  {
/* styles here */
}
```